# Program that can display real types of files in a directory

Tags: windows, file-management, file-format

I am looking for a program that can show the actual types of files in a directory.  The program would have to analyze the headers/contents of the files in the directory in order to determine their types.

This would be useful for browser cache directories, which frequently contain renamed files without any file extensions.  The program would analyze the files in such a directory and indicate whether each file is JPG/PNG/HTML/CSS/JS/etc.

The program must run on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The Linux/Unix/Gnu `file` utility can do that , and it should be available in the Windows/Linux Subsystem thing.  If not, there were Win32 builds available which may work on a Win 10 64bit machine, and if not, the source is available.

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm

Comment: Or, failing that, install Cygwin. Great answer (+1)

Comment: Yay!  I Googled and found a Windows version at http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm